# Path resizing script for adobe illustrator

Tags: scripting, path, resize, scale, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to resize multiple paths (100 +) within my illustrator document. There are too many path objects to resize individually.

So I was wondering - Is there a script/how would you go about - uniformly resizing each path (a circle ) so that each circle was 2px larger than previously.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - Transform Each does it.
Just a matter of time before I found that function